# IBM Worklight 6.1 - How to create a plug-in for a Windows 8 Store app?

Tags: c#, cordova, windows-8, ibm-mobilefirst

I have tried to create a plug-in for Windows 8 Store without success...
Anybody created a plug-in for a Windows 8 Store app? If yes then please tell me steps to create it?

Comment: See my answer. Is this question resolved?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to write Windows 8 Store apps in several languages: C++, C#, or web technologies like HTML, JavaScript and CSS. These are then packaged and distributed to the Windows Store via the Visual Studio IDE.

In Worklight, the Windows 8 Store apps are written using web technologies.

- [Developing Windows Store Apps with HTML5 Jump Start](http://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/training-courses/developing-windows-store-apps-with-html5-jump-start)

Here, the notion of "plug-in" does not exist, because the underlying of the application is based on "web code" rather than "native code". Hence, the Windows 8 environment in Worklight does not support the creation of Cordova plug-ins (to interface with native libraries).

You can use [Cordova APIs](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.1.0/index.html) to access hardware features and alike.
You can also use the WinJS API provided by Microsoft:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465493.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br229773.aspx